# Javamail SMTPSenderFailedException 553

Tags: smtp, gmail, jakarta-mail

This code was working fine for months but has suddenly stopped working without any change in the code. The exception stack trace has:

```
 com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSenderFailedException: 553 5.1.2 The address specified is not a valid RFC-5321 address. tj2sm1495299pab.4 - gsmtp
```

My code, which was working earlier:

```
    final String username = uName;

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    props.put("mail.smtp.debug", "true");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
        }
    });

    try {
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);

        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("<from email id>"));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("<to email address>"));
        message.setSubject("<subject>");
        message.setContent(finalMessage, "text/html");

        Transport.send(message);

    } catch (MessagingException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.error("Emailing error: "+e.getMessage());
    }
```

This stopped working today.

Comment: Have you looked at the email address to see if it is valid? Of course you cannot show it here without the owner's permission, but the issue may be obvious. (Or is it the `tj2sm1495299pab.4`? - if so that's clearly not an email address).

Comment: yes, I have tried with multiple email addresses. found this link where others seem to have the same issue but no solution: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/2tK2fR7yW-k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the "from email id" for the complete email adress

Google has change the last week the validation from standar RFC 5321 that covers the field "FROM"

Answer (score 2):

What did it for me was changing the username-field content from "username" to "username@gmail.com".

Comment: can't believe this was the cause of the problem but it was working fine for months

Comment: I encountered the same error but my username content already had an "@gmail.com" at the end.